# Convert Hashtag #term in WordPress Content Post by Taxonomy Tag without # Symbol

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, hashtag

I convert the terms preceded by the symbol # into Tag taxonomy using this snippet:

```
function post_published_notification( $ID, $post ) {
    $content = $post->post_content;
    preg_match_all('/( #\w+)/', $content, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    if(isset($matches[1])){
        foreach($matches[1] as $matchKey){
            wp_set_post_tags( $ID, trim($matchKey), true);
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'post_published_notification', 10, 2 );
```

Tags are saved like this: #MyTag

I want them to be saved without the # symbol like this: MyTag

How to fix this code?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Move the ` #` part of the pattern outside of the capturing group?

Comment: I tried this: '/ #([0-9a-zA-Z _]+)/' but it still saves the tag with the symbol